# How to handle blank values in FOR XML PATH/AUTO - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, special-characters

Does anybody have any insight or encountered with this SQL Server behavior,
when blank value is converted into data type "`char`" or column which have "`char`" as data type - processed using `For XML PATH`, it returned XML result with "`&#20;`" special characters encoding for space,
When same blank value converted with `varchar` - it returns empty tag. My desired result is empty tag.

```
SELECT field=CONVERT(CHAR(10),'')
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS
--RESULT: <field>          &#x20;</field>

SELECT field=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'')
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS
--RESULT: <field></field>
```

The explanation in my view is when I'm using `char` it is inserting 10 spaces. And ASCII Hex20 or Decimal 32 - is a code for space.

It can be handled by using `varchar` instead of char as data type. But in my case I am reading field value from table defined in database:

```
--Example:
CREATE TABLE #temp(field CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT NULL

SELECT field=ISNULL(field,'')
FROM #temp
FOR XML PATH('')

DROP TABLE #temp

--RESULT: <field>  &#x20;</field>
--Desired Result:<field></field>
```

What is a most elegant way/or possibilities in SQL?

PS: I have a result set of 50 columns. I would like to handle this at database level without changing types. Real problem is my web service when encounter this character in XML throws a potentially dangerous value error.

Comment: As I found when SQL Server stores char type data a `0x0200` at the end of each value will add, I think this hex cause that ;).

Answer (score 1):

Solution I used for desired result is, casting a whole result at once -

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(field CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT NULL

--Adding a cast to XML Result to convert it into varchar & then use replace.
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),(SELECT field=ISNULL(field,'')
FROM #temp
FOR XML PATH(''))),'&#x20;','')

DROP TABLE #temp
```

would like to hear if there is any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following...up to you if you feel you need to TRIM or not;

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(field CHAR(2))

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT NULL

SELECT field=COALESCE(NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(field)), ''), '')
FROM #temp
FOR XML PATH('')

DROP TABLE #temp
```