# Update or replace a special character text in my database field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am facing to an issue that I cannot update or replace some characters in my database.
Here is how this text look like in my column when I retrieve it:

[image]

As you can see, there is an unknown characters between 'master' and 'degree' which I cannot even paste it here.

I also tried to update and replace it with below code (I cannot paste that two vertical lines here since they are not supported in any browser and I am not sure what they are, Please see the picture above to see what is in my SQL statement).

```
begin transaction
update gm_desc set projdesc=replace(projdesc,'%â  s%','') where projdesc like '%âs%' and proposalno = '15-149-01'
```

You can see the real SQL Statement here:

[image]

I tried to update, or replace it but I cannot do it. The update statement successfully works but I still see that weird special charters. I would be appreciate to help me.

Comment: Is `projdesc` an `NVarChar`? Have you tried matching characters _not_ in a set, e.g. `like '%[^a-z0-9]%'` to find the rows? You can dump the column in hexadecimal to get the character values, e.g. `select projdesc, Cast( projdesc as VarBinary(1000) ) as Hex from gm_desc where projectdesc like '%[^a-z0-9 ]%';`.

Comment: To support HABO's comment: I'm pretty sure, that this is some kind of 2-byte encoded *apostrophe character* representing *"master's degree"*. First of all you should find out your string's encoding. The cast to `VARBINARY(MAX)` - as suggested by @HABO - will  help you to see the internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a scalar-valued function which removes all non-alphanumeric characters (preserves spaces) from a string.

Hopefully it helps!

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=41d396e131843b1420e1a1748570be3e)

```sql
create function dbo.get_alphanumeric_str
(
    @string varchar(max)
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

    declare @ret varchar(max);

    with nums as (
        select 1 as n
        union all select n+1 from nums
        where n < 256
    )
    select @ret = replace(stuff(
        (
            select '' + substring(@string, nums.n, 1)
            from nums
            where patindex('%[^0-9A-Za-z ]%', substring(@string, nums.n,1)) = 0 
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 0, ''
    ), '&#x20;', ' ')
    option (MAXRECURSION 256)

    return @ret;
end
```

## Usage

```sql
select dbo.get_alphanumeric_str('Helloᶄ âWorld 1234⅊⅐')
```

Returns: `Hello World 1234`

## How it works

- The `nums` CTE is just to get a list of numbers (you can set the maximum of `256` to a higher value if your strings are longer; n.b. `option (MAXRECURSION n)` is for this CTE but has to be placed at the query)
- The `stuff` essentially *iterates* through the string, using the list of numbers above and extracts a substring of length 1; each of these chars are checked if they match the `[^0-9A-Za-z ]` regex group (`0-9` all digits, `A-Za-z` all letters both lower and upper case, and a single space character)
- If they match, `patindex()` should return 0; i.e. index zero.
- Use `replace(string, '&#x20;', ' ')` for the space character as the `xml path` returns a special encoding, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700436/how-to-handle-blank-values-in-for-xml-path-auto-sql-server).
- Use a binary collation for accented characters; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43128125/7455070)

Comment: In this case I'm pretty sure, that this won't help, at least not in a sure way. Assumably the given text stands for *"master's degree"*, where the *strange characters* are the 2-byte encoded apostrophe. Your function accepts only 1-byte encoded text (`varchar`) and returns as such. If my assumption is true, you would not get the original text, but the text without the apostrophe. In other cases you might return additional characters (in cases, where one byte of the 2-byte-code-point translates to a plain character by chance).

Comment: Thank you so much I will check it today. I appreciate your valuable time